# statsmodels.formula.api importError: cannot import name 'TimeSeries'

Tags: python-3.x, statsmodels

New to python here.

Using the following:
Anaconda - v1.3.1
Spyder - v3.1.4
Python - v3.5

I am trying to import the following libraries:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
```

It keeps giving me the following error:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-2515cefb61aa>", line 1, in <module>
    import statsmodels.formula.api as sm

  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/statsmodels/formula/api.py", line 1, in <module>
    from statsmodels.regression.linear_model import GLS

  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .linear_model import yule_walker

  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py", line 52, in <module>
    import statsmodels.base.model as base

  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/statsmodels/base/model.py", line 5, in <module>
    from statsmodels.base.data import handle_data

  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/statsmodels/base/data.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pandas import DataFrame, Series, TimeSeries, isnull

ImportError: cannot import name 'TimeSeries'
```

I read some posts about updating pandas. I tried that but it doesn't work. Any ideas as to the error and a solution? (It works fine when I import only statsmodel.formula or just statsmodel)

Comment: What happens when you do `from pandas import TimeSeries` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **python3**:

You need to upgrade statsmodels. If that is a problem go for a specific version such as:

`py -m pip install statsmodels==0.6.0`

Then you can use

`py -m pip install statsmodels --upgrade`

For python2.x

`pip install statsmodels --upgrade`

Answer (score 16):

Upgrading statsmodels worked for me,

`pip install statsmodels --upgrade`

Comment: `conda upgrade statsmodels` might be preferable if using Anaconda, for future version compatibility

Comment: Restart kernel if using Jupyter notebooks after the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

The above solutions didn't quite worked for me when working on azure databricks. But one thing worked for me, which I am not sure why. So when I restarted my notebook and imported as listed below it worked. Please comment if this worked for you and also in case you may have any idea why this worked.

```
    import statsmodels
    import statsmodels.api as sm
    import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

> import statsmodels.api as sm